Transition properties not applying on div's
I have a div containing 5 divs with display grid and wanted to add a transition effect but its not adding. it just applies change without delay or effect.
I have defined the transition in the parent as well as the div itself but it is not applying.


.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 35vw;

  margin-left: 25.5vw;
  margin-top: 5.725vw;
  margin-bottom: 5.75vw;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;

  gap: 1vw;

  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container div {
  background-color: #32363e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;

  opacity: 0.8;

  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

  padding: 1vw;
}

.container:has(div:hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.proj1:hover {
  grid-column: span 7;
}
.proj2:hover {
  grid-column: span 7;
}
.proj3:hover {
  grid-column: span 7;
}
.proj4:hover {
  grid-column: span 7;
}
.proj5:hover {
  grid-column: span 7;
}
<div class="container" id="Projects">
      <div class="proj1"></div>
      <div class="proj1"></div>
      <div class="proj1"></div>
      <div class="proj1"></div>
      <div class="proj1"></div>
    </div>



